# Vertical margin of a span inside a paragraph

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website which will include math that I'd like to be presented in a neat way. I'm turning away from LaTeX for now (unfortunately - not my choice) so I've created a simple CSS class for math. This is what the HTML looks like.

```html
<p>
  Text goes here <br>
  <span class="math">Math goes here</span><br>
  More text<br>
  <span class="math">More math</span>
</p>
```

The spans used to be divs, but I found you can't have divs in paragraphs. However, I'd like the spans to have some vertical spacing. Since I can't use divs and spans can't have vertical spacing, what's my best solution here? Is it passable to not use a p tag in this case?

Thanks in advance, I appreciate your time.

Comment: Why not just close the pargraph instead of using a break tag?

Comment: Yeah, that'd definitely work. I just thought it'd be cluttery if every text bit was it's own paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the spans to `display:inline-block` and add vertical padding.

```css
span {
  background: pink;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Text goes here <br>
  <span class="math">Math goes here</span><br>
  More text<br>
  <span class="math">More math</span>
</p
```

Frankly, though the simplest method would be to just close the paragraphs instead of using break tags and letting the natural margins do the work for you.

```css
span {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<p>Text goes here</p>
<span class="math">Math goes here</span>
<p>More text</p>
<span class="math">More math</span>
```

Comment: Is it problematic that all of this happens in a div? I'm getting weird spacing with replacing br tags with </p> tags. Like, double spacing on top of and none below the math.

Comment: Well paragraps do have default margin but that's fixable.

Comment: For instance - https://jsfiddle.net/89878akd/ If you show us how you want this to look we can offer more cogent advice,

Comment: Okay, I think the solution I'll go with is to have the paragraphs as you suggest and use divs instead of spans. Looks nice. Your advice has been insightful, and I appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `line-height` and `display:inline` for span element:

```css
p span {
  background: pink;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height:50px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Text goes here <br>
  <span class="math">Math goes here</span><br>
  More text<br>
  <span class="math">More math</span>
</p
```